# How to fix textarea to bottom of screen within a scrolling div

Tags: html, css

Need to fix textarea to the bottom of a div that is scrollable, but not have the textarea spill out of the div like it does when I try to put `position: fixed` to fix it to the bottom.

If you have a grid layout where there is a scrolling set of text how do you set the text area at the bottom. I have tried `position: fixed;` and it stretches the width of the entire screen. I need the `textarea` to fit directly inside the left div. When I use `position: relative` in the scrolling text `div` and use `position: absolute;` in the textarea it puts the textarea at the bottom of the screen but it doesn't stay there when I scroll.

This is what I currently have:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMMjow

This is what I want, but have it pin to the bottom like above:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjjMVK

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding another element parallel with textarea and make textarea to bottom of first div.

```css
.messages{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.message{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.textarea{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  resize: none;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="messages">
  <div class="message">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="textarea"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "sticky-footer" method on the `textarea` to keep it always at the bottom, regardless of the content size. This uses the a negative margin on the content wrapper:

```css
body {
  background: #fafafa;
}

.mdl-grid {
  padding: 0!important;
  margin-bottom: -25px !important;
}

.messages {
  position: relative;
}

.mdl-cell {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height:93vh;
  background: #bdbdbd;
  padding: 0!important;
  text-align: center;
  color: #424242;
  font-weight: bold;
}

textarea {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 98%;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mdl-grid">
      <div class="messages mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<
        <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col">8</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```